# can a class be called upon from within a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi I wanted to know if it is possible to call a class repeatedly from within a loop

```
for x in range(0,numLines):
        line = myFile.readline()
        sLine = line.split(",")
        town1 = towns.Towns(sLine[0],sLine[1],sLine[2],sLine[3])
        pop = int(town1.population)
        if ((pop >= lower) and (pop <= upper)):
            print(line)
```

as every time I try to implement this I get an error code of list index is out of range.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That's because `sLine` doesn't have enough elements; it has nothing to do with creating the class itself. Perhaps your file is empty and `myFile.readline()` returned an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `towns.Towns` in a loop just fine. Your problem comes from something else. My guess is that you have empty lines in the file, so `line.split(",")` doesn't actually have 4 elements.